# Delete user profile in firebase storage delete everything

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a simple app where user can upload a profile image.
The function for upload works.
I want a button to delete the user account and at the same time delete the user image from the firebase storage.

This is the simple function to delete the user picture:

```
  const deleteUserAccount = () => {
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref(`users/${user.uid}/profile.jpg`)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('image deleted');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

if I execute the function the whole "users" folder is deleted not only the one corresponding to the userId of the user.
I just want to delete the corresponding {user.uid} folder.

Here my storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{users}/{uid}/{profileImage} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is nothing else but the `profile.jpg` in the folder, the behavior is actually as expected. Folders in Cloud Storage are auto-created and deleted as files are added and deleted. You can't have a folder without a file in (through the API).

Comment: ooh you're right! the fact is that I was doing tests with only one user so in the "users" folder there is only one folder with the uid .. and running the function I did not understand why it deleted everything ... I did the test by creating another folder of another hypothetical user and now, in fact, it only deletes the one of the uid in question! I thank you!

Comment: Good to hear that was it  You inspired me to also tweet about it: https://twitter.com/puf/status/1438183905765462017